# Vue.js - Listener @oninput.native is not called in b-form-textarea

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, bootstrap-vue

I have Vue app and I would like to add Facebook inspired buttons in-lined in a comment form. I had plain JS prototype that was working. When I tried to incorporate it into the Vue app I faced an issue with multiple occurrences of the component on the page because it heavily used element id. I would be able to declare dynamic id but this approach was not working well because `<style>` is static. I found `refs` later and got inspired by this wonderful article: https://www.telerik.com/blogs/how-to-target-the-dom-in-vue. Long story short: my callback is never called.

[Code sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/black-mountain-tryro?file=/src/components/Form.vue:502-518)

Source code:

```
<b-form-textarea
  class="textarea" ref="textareaRef"
  rows="1" max-rows="8"
  @oninput.native = "adjustIconsInTextarea"
  :placeholder="$t('comment.write-comment-placeholder')"
  v-model="text"
>

<div class="icons" ref="iconsRef">
  <b-button :id="`emoji_list_${commentId}`" class="mt-2" variant="outline" size="sm">
    &#x1F600;
  </b-button>
</div>

methods: {
adjustIconsInTextarea() {
  const textComment = this.$refs.textareaRef;
  console.log(textComment.value.length);
  const icons = this.$refs.iconsRef;
  if (textComment.value.length > 140) {
    textComment.style.padding = '13px 50px 34px 32px';
    icons.style.top = '-36px';
    icons.style.right = '72px';
  } else {
    textComment.style.padding = '10px 174px 5px 28px';
    icons.style.top = '-45px';
    icons.style.right = '68px';
  }
},
```

Bootstrap-vue `b-form-textarea`'s [events](https://bootstrap-vue.org/docs/components/form-textarea#native-and-custom-events). Where is the error?

Comment: you should use `@input= "adjustIconsInTextarea"`

Comment: That's it, thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [`docs`](https://bootstrap-vue.org/docs/components/form-textarea#native-and-custom-events):

> All native events (other than the custom `input` and `change` events) are supported, without the need for the `.native` modifier.

so you should do :

```
@input= "adjustIconsInTextarea"
```

and pass use the `event` parameter target instead of `refs` for the textarea :

```
methods: {
adjustIconsInTextarea(event) {
  const textComment = event.target;
  console.log(textComment.value.length);
  const icons = this.$refs.iconsRef;
  if (textComment.value.length > 140) {
    textComment.style.padding = '13px 50px 34px 32px';
    icons.style.top = '-36px';
    icons.style.right = '72px';
  } else {
    textComment.style.padding = '10px 174px 5px 28px';
    icons.style.top = '-45px';
    icons.style.right = '68px';
  }
},
```

Comment: Thanks for your hint. Now the problem is that vue component does not have the style property like DOM element.

Comment: New question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63166772/apply-css-style-for-textarea-based-on-text-length