# Vue.js - Apply CSS style for textarea based on text length

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, bootstrap-vue

I have Vue app and I would like to add Facebook inspired buttons inlined in a comment form. I had plain JS prototype that was working. But I cannot make it work inside Vue component. I have implemented two variants, both are called but the style is not changed in either.

1. callback listening to the input event
2. condition in the class attribute

The sandbox is there: https://codesandbox.io/s/black-mountain-tryro

Callback variant:

```
<b-form-textarea
  class="textarea"
  ref="textareaRef"
  rows="1"
  max-rows="8"
  @input="adjustIconsInTextarea"
  placeholder="Type something"
  v-model="text"
></b-form-textarea>

adjustIconsInTextarea() {
  const textComment = this.$refs.textareaRef;
  const icons = this.$refs.iconsRef;
  if (textComment.value.length > 140) {
    textComment.style.padding = "13px 50px 34px 32px";
    icons.style.top = "-36px";
    icons.style.right = "72px";
  } else {
    textComment.style.padding = "10px 174px 5px 28px";
    icons.style.top = "-45px";
    icons.style.right = "68px";
  }
},
```

This one fails that Vue component has no syle property: `textComment.style.padding`

CSS variant:

```
<b-form-textarea
  class="textarea"
  :class="wrapIcons ? 'textarea_short' : 'textarea_long'"
  rows="1"
  max-rows="8"
  placeholder="Type text"
  v-model="text"
></b-form-textarea>

computed: {
  wrapIcons() {
    return this.text.length > 140;
  }

.textarea {
  height: 40px;
  overflow-y: hidden;
}

.textarea_short {
  padding: 10px 174px 5px 28px;
}

.textarea_long {
  padding: 13px 50px 34px 32px;
}
```

This one does not modify the style regardless of wrapText computed property value.

How to make it work? Which approach is better?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your class syntax is wrong. `:class` expects an object with the class name as key and `true` or `false` as values. Try it like this:

```
:class="{icons_long: !wrapIcons}"
```

In my opinion, i would go with the CSS approach

Answer (score 1):

Another and valid syntax is keeping your own and adding back tick *`* and string interpolation :

```
:class="`${wrapIcons ? 'textarea_short' : 'textarea_long'}`"
```